# jquery variables, functions and the wrap tag (beginner)

Tags: jquery

**Issues 1:**

```
$('#msg').html($('#quote').text());
```

now changed quote for a variable - quotevar:

```
$("#msg").html(quotevar);
```

How would I incorporate the text function there to get the same result I did with #quote? I can't even seem to understand how to properly handle variables and functions in jquery.

**Issue 2:**

I need to add [quote] [/quote] bbode tags **around** my variable quotevar. This is actually the reason I created the variable in issue 1.

If it's possible to do it without the new var using this:
`$('#msg').html($('#quote').text());` then I'd like to know how that is done also.

I assume the wrap() function is needed to add the tags.

Comment: You seem to need to learn Javascript

Comment: I am and just did quite a bit. It may seem extremely easy but I get stuck at places like this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I understand you correctly, are you just wanting to do this?

```
var quotevar = "<quote>" + $('#quote').text() + "</quote>";
```

or using `wrap()`

```
var quotevar = $('#quote').text().wrap("<quote />");
$('#msg').html(quotevar);
```

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I wanted.

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Object test has no method 'wrap'`

Comment: Just did, thanks again. Didn't know I'm supposed to do that - I'm new to the site.